# Pop and push functions at stack Linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack

Hello I have created two functions pop and push. The problem is that the program crashes after the pop function and I can not figure why. I will be happy if you can help me.

```
Struct Node
{
  int num;
  Node *next;
};

void push(Node** top, int num)
{
 Node* tmp = *top;
 Node* newNode = new Node;
 newNode->num = num;
 *top = newNode;
 newNode->next = tmp;
```

}

```
int pop(Node* top)
{
 Node *poppedLink = top;
 top = poppedLink->next; 
 int ans = poppedLink->num; 
 delete poppedLink; 

 return ans;
```

}

Comment: Your `Node` definition shouldn't compile.

Comment: Sorry I forgot part Its (corrected)

Comment: It's better now, but there's no **S**truct keyword in c++.

Answer (score 3):

You delete the node but outer code doesn't aware of this and keep using old pointer to "top" (which is dead already). You have to use double-pointer as input param like it happens in push().

Something like this (sorry, I didn't test it on the compiler):

```
int pop(Node** top)
{
 Node *poppedLink = *top;
 *top = poppedLink->next; 
 int ans = poppedLink->num; 
 delete poppedLink; 

 return ans;
}
```